# How to use Array deconstruction in Typescript with no Error?

Tags: typescript

I wrote some code in Typescript:

```
for (const [a, b] of [['1', 2],['3', 4]]) {
  console.log(a.substr(0));
}
```

In javascript, it works, and outputs:

```
1
3
```

But in Typescript，that will cause an compile error near `substr`:

```
TS2339: Property 'substr' does not exist on type 'string | number'.   Property 'substr' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

Seems like the compiler cannot confirm the type of a, from string/number.

I think it's a bug of TypeScript. Am I wrong? Or if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug. Basically, when you write `['1', 2]`, Typescript will understand it as `<string | number>[]` instead of `[string, number]`. So if you want to force it to [number, string], you have to define the type

```
  for (const [a, b] of <[string, number][]>[['1', 2],['3', 4]]) {
    console.log(a.substr(0));
  }
```